# android custom ui library is not working

Tags: android-layout, android

I was trying to implement this:https://github.com/daimajia/NumberProgressBar   github library in my project .here is my xml  file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"     android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.daimajia.numberprogressbar.NumberProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/number_progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

java file:

```
package com.example.buck.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import com.daimajia.numberprogressbar.NumberProgressBar;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


}
```

}

but it show following error [image]

I dont know what to do please help me out;

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't your IDE indicate there's errors in the layout file?

I think you're missing a line there; add something like this (I'm not sure it's 100% correct as I haven't used that project):

```
xmlns:daimajia="http://schemas.android.com/apk/com.daimajia"
```

to the root RelativeLayout in the layout file.

Answer (score 0):

create a file named "attr.xml" inside res/values folder.

and put this code into it

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
   <declare-styleable name="NumberProgressBar">
      <attr name="progress" format="integer"/>
      <attr name="max" format="integer"/>

      <attr name="progress_unreached_color" format="color"/>
      <attr name="progress_reached_color" format="color"/>

      <attr name="progress_reached_bar_height" format="dimension"/>
      <attr name="progress_unreached_bar_height" format="dimension"/>

      <attr name="progress_text_size" format="dimension"/>
      <attr name="progress_text_color" format="color"/>

      <attr name="progress_text_offset" format="dimension"/>

      <attr name="progress_text_visibility" format="enum">
        <enum name="visible" value="0"/>
        <enum name="invisible" value="1"/>
      </attr>
   </declare-styleable>

   <declare-styleable name="Themes">
      <attr name="numberProgressBarStyle" format="reference"/>
   </declare-styleable>
 </resources>
```

You need to define the styles your library project uses.
Hope it will help.Thanks